# How to pass a variable in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a candidate search view.

I want to search for candidates with this view, and then if the view was called from clicking on an edit candidate `< a href`, i want to find the candidate then display in an update view.

If the view was called from clicking on read candidate details `< a href`, i want to find the candidate then just display a detail view of the candidate.

I somehow need to call the one view, but to pass it a parameter.
normally i pass parameters using:

```
(?P<pk>\d+/$)
```

but i am not sure how to pass a parameter that says 'update' or 'read'.

I don't know if i should use `get_context_data`, or if i should use some

```
**kwargs
```

(ps if i use **kwargs) i don't know how to pull this off.
or if i should use a regex field in the url which is set in the

```
<ahref
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as you can see i am confused as to when to use:

```
**kwargs
(?P<pk>
get_context_data
```

In the generic class based view.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you want these to be a single view. Displaying and editing details are two separate things, they should be two separate views.

Comment: Ah ok thanks Dainel Roseman, i didn't know. I am more than happy to use 2 seperate views. I was going for the one view because, both situations have to query the candidate name. I was trying to use the DRY principle, and i am quite new to django and python.